# Rigorous proof of a limit

Tags: analysis, limits

Guys I'm feeling a bit rusty in analysis... How do I prove that

$$\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{e^{- x^2/y}}{\sqrt y} = 0$$

With $x\neq 0$. I have tried the approach with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ but I've got nothing out of it... Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $-x^{2}/y$ in the exponent...?

Comment: should the $t$ be a $y$?

Comment: It's finite. Because the exponential at the numerator goes to zero faster then the denominator

Comment: We are looking at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}e^{a/y}}$. First prove the inequality $e^t\ge 1+t\gt t$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put at good use your tip...

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing the substitution $y \to 1/t^2$ reveals

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-x^2/y}}{\sqrt{y}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-x^2t^2}=0$$

for $x\ne0$ since for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\begin{align}
\left|te^{-x^2t^2}\right|&\le \frac{|t|}{1+x^2t^2}\\\\
&<\frac{|t|}{t^2x^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2|t|}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|t|>B=\frac{1}{x^2\epsilon}$ or equivalently whenever $0<y<\delta=|x|\sqrt{\epsilon}$

Comment: I was going to give almost the same answer with $y = 1/t$ substitution and the use of $e^{x} \geq 1 + x$ inequality but then I noticed yours. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks!!  Hope you're doing well.  And nice to see you back!

Answer (score 0):

### HINT:

From $e^x = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$, you have:

$$ e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{y}} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)^2}{2} + \frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)^3}{3!} \cdots} \\
 = \dfrac{y}{x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2y} + \cdots}$$

Answer (score 0):

ale42 had the right answer, intuitively-speaking, in the comments. I slightly rigorous justification is that (for a couple steps below, we will need that $y > 0$)
$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \left| \frac{e^{- x^2/y}}{\sqrt y} \right|
= 
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y} \left| (1 + \frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{x^4 / y^2}{2!} + \cdots) \right| }
=
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y} (1 + \left| \frac{x^2}{y} \right| + \left| \frac{x^4 / y^2}{2!} \right| + \cdots) } 
\leq
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y} (1 + \left| \frac{x^2}{y} \right|) }
=
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{y}}{y + x^2 }
\to 0 \text{ if } x \neq 0.
$$
and so 
$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{e^{- x^2/y}}{\sqrt y} = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any reference to suggest me for improving my rigour with limits?

Comment: Hey, I cleaned up a typo I noticed on rereading, the old inequality on using the triangle inequality actually becomes an equality, which we need as the inequality would technically be the other way and would mess up the argument I was going for. Unfortunately, I don't really have any particular references. Maybe look for a problem book in analysis or advanced limits? I don't know any particulars though. The techniques used here are the taylor series for a function to get asymptotic expansion, triangle inequality, and simple fractional inequalities. Sometimes it is helpful to look at $|f|$.

Comment: @ale42 see above comment. (sorry, can't edit it now) Just wanted to point out that I originally looked at $|f|$ because I wanted to get a $\sqrt{y}$ term to work with the other, and forgot that there was an easier way to do this, esp. as $y > 0$. Still, looking at $|f|$ can sometimes be useful

Comment: Yep, I've read it :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{e^{- x^2/y}}{\sqrt y}=\lim_{t \to \infty } \frac{\sqrt t}{e^{tx^2}} = \lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt t} \frac{t}{e^{tx^2}} \tag1$$
Using L'Hospital:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{t}{e^{tx^2}} = \lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{1}{x^2e^{tx^2}}=0 
$$
and : $$\lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt t}=0$$
from (1) we get the result.

Comment: I would avoid using de L'Hôpital when a rigorous answer is needeed...

Comment: @ale42 Do you think L'Hospital is not rigorous?

Comment: I would say that de L'Hôpital is particularly useful for computing limits, not for showing that the limit value is exactly the one that comes out by using his formula. Have you have ever seen a notable limit that is proven with his formula? :P Anyway, it's matter of taste. :)